# android: problem setting up intent filter to fire off activity when downloading file from web in browser

Tags: android, browser, intentfilter

I am having a problem getting an activity to be initiated in response to a file download from a browser window.

When I click the file download button in broswer it gets downloaded to SD card, rather than firing off my MainActivity (or even prompting what I should do with it).

If I then locate the file on the SD card using a file explorer and select it then my MainActivity is initiated.

Have I misunderstood how intent filters work? I have verified the mime type for the download file using wireshark on a pc to verify that it is as expected.

[ If i remove the PathPattern and simply have the mime type in place then when pressing the download button I am prompted saying that there is nothing on the device to handle this file and do I still want to go ahead with the download.]

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the entry from my manifest:

```
 <activity android:name=".activity.main.MainActivity"
           android:label="@string/app_name">

     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>

     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/xml-mydata" 
              android:pathPattern=".*\\.mydata" />
     </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

Comment: OK With pathPattern removed the file downloads OK, my previous comment (to commonsware) about it now not working at all was incorrect.Been reading up a bit more esp about DownloadManager and I suspect that the behaviour I am seeing is correct. ie click on button to download file from web site, downloadManger downloads the file and stores it on SD card. My application only receives an intent when the file is selected in the file explorer. So I am now confused at to what the BROWSABLE category brings to the party. And is it possible to fire off an activity automatically for downloadable file?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually what you have seems fine, though I would dump the `pathPattern`. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Introspection/URLHandler) demonstrating these sorts of `<intent-filter>` elements.

I would make sure that your MIME type has valid syntax. I forget off the top of my head if dashes are allowed.

Comment: Dashes do seem to be allowed as part of the mime syntax (see here http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/index.html for some examples). Have tried without the pathPattern and then type is not recognised as being supported anywhere.

Comment: @malcooke: All I can tell you is to try my sample app. If it works -- and it did the last time I tried it -- then you need to start to determine where you differ from what I have. For example, perhaps there's something subtly wrong with the MIME type that you're not catching via Wireshark.

Comment: Ok I did set up your sample app and it seems to work in the same way that my app works. ie it did not automatically fire off the pdf viewer when the file was downloaded. The behaviour I am seeing is that the file gets downloaded, and then when select the file name from the notification then the pdf reader is triggered. Just to make sure it wasn't a feature of htc sense on my desire, I repeated the trial on the emulator with the same result. Perhaps this is the normal way of working?

Comment: @malcookie: Sorry, I must have been mis-remembering the behavior.